# How to create .ts files for Qt Linguist with PySide6?

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I have a python project written with PySide2 and now I want to migrate to PySide6. I used Qt Linguist to translate UI and created `.ts` files with help of this command:
`pylupdate5` utility from PyQt5 package (but it worked fine for my project with PySide2). Now I plan to get rid of PySide2 and PyQt5 packages.

So, I need to replace `pylupdate5` with something from PySide6 package. I assumed `lupdate` should to the job but it seems it works only with C++ code. It gives me errors like `Unterminated C++ character` or `Unbalanced opening parenthesis in C++ code`. An with `lupdate -help` I don't see how I may switch it to python mode (similar to `uic -g python`).

Does anyone know how to create `.ts` files for Qt Linguist from python source files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lupdate of Qt 6.1 does not support Python but in Qt 6.2 that problem no longer exists so you have 2 options:

- Install Qt 6.2 and use its lupdate.
- Wait for PySide6 6.2.0 to be released (at this moment it is only available for windows) and use lupdate.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I used old `lupdate`. I updated to 6.2 and it doesn't throw these errors.